# Can a Cargo feature enable features from optional dependencies without forcing those crates to be activated?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

This is the Cargo.toml for a library crate.  It supports two different embedded boards by having optional dependencies on board support crates `board-a` and `board-b`, and only one of these is selected by running `cargo build --features target-a`.

There is also a common third-party module, which optionally uses the `const-fn` feature.  This option is exposed in the library crate:

```
[dependencies]
common = {...}
board-a = {optional=true, ...}
board-b = {optional=true, ...}

[features]
const-fn = ["common/const-fn"]
target-a = ["board-a"]
target-b = ["board-b"]
```

So far so good, but what if the `board-a` and `board-b` crates also have optional `const-fn` features, and I want to expose those options to users of the library crate?  Can I do this without creating `target-a-const-fn` and `target-b-const-fn` features?  That would obviously get very messy the more optional features I expose, or the more boards that we support.

I don't want to make the `const-fn` feature pull in both board crates -- only the selected one should be used, otherwise it would needlessly increase the download and compile times.  Ideally I want something equivalent to the following, but as far as I can see nothing remotely like it exists:

```
[features]
const-fn = ["common/const-fn", "board-a/const-fn" if target-a, "board-b/const-fn" if target-b]
target-a = ...
```

Comment: *increase the download [,,,] times* — I thought that all the dependencies, optional or not, would be downloaded anyway...

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible since Rust 1.60:

```
[features]
const-fn = ["common/const-fn", "board-a?/const-fn", "board-b?/const-fn"]
```

The feature is called weak dependency features. You can read the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#dependency-features) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported currently by Cargo, although there is [a tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8832) for this feature.